# Late 2009 MBP 15" battery drain on sleep after putting SSD and ram upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, upgrade, battery, ssd

I have a 2009 MacBook Pro (macbook pro 5.4) with Core 2 duo 2.53ghz 4GB RAM with 256 HDD.
I upgraded the RAM and switched to SSD. Here are the specs:

Crucial M4 CT256M4SSD2 2.5" 256GB SATA III MLC Internal Solid State Drive (SSD)

Crucial 8GB (2 x 4GB) 204-Pin DDR3 SO-DIMM DDR3 1066 (PC3 8500) Laptop Memory Model CT2KIT51264BC1067

My problem is that after upgrading my laptop drains significantly more battery while on sleep. Like 15% per day, before upgrade it drained like 1-2% per day on sleep.

I'm on Mavericks but with upgrades, so not a fresh install, I also enabled the trim support for the SSD with a third party app. I tried SMC reset at some point as well. I have the latest firmware update.

Comment: Look in the Console to see who is active during the sleep, and publish it here.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Can you give me a command to see who is active during sleep? Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible you are still in the 'fase' of spotlight indexing? If so, your problems might go away after everything is properly indexed.

Comment: @CousinCocaine It's in this state like a year or so.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have one of the following enabled that could explain the power drain.

Power Nap or Wake on WiFi, disable them,

or read the small print that says what it will do in sleep :)

[image: sleep mode]

Also as said earlier, open the Console and type "Wake" in the search window of the Console.

Now look who and what is waking it up and what is it  for what reason and what is it doing about it.

As for your question why is it consuming more power, well you added more lights to the Christmas tree.

For example when HDD sleeps it does not consumes any power. The cussing SSD does consume power since it reshuffle it self from time to time, that is normal for SSD to refresh its memory cells.

UPDATE:

[according to apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5394), you computer does not support the Power Nap mode settings thus enable/disable activity during the sleep.

So back to the Console reports:

Type "Wake" and look what is waking it up or keeping it awake based on time stamps.

Going on a limb, I would say it is your Trim support for the SSD, that you will find in the Console.

The TRIM command is an important disk command for SSDs that keeps your flash memory appropriately cycled so that you can achieve faster read and write speeds, as well as a longer lifespan for your SSD.

Comment: Thanks, I will post when I arrive home. The thing is that I don't have the Enable power nap option present in this screen.

Comment: There is a thread on macrumors.com where one person mentions:'It looks like the feature requires one of the "blade" style SSDs, not the sort that is made to replace a 2.5" hard drive.' http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1410839